# Ionic 4 Deeplink plugin return false route not matched

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, deep-linking, hybrid-mobile-app

I am Implementing Deeplink in ionic 4 application. Application in getting launched but deeplink plugin always returns `false`;

app.routing.ts:

```
{
    path: 'viewdiary/:id/public',    
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/viewdiary/viewdiary.module').then( m => m.ViewdiaryPageModule)
  },
```

app.compoent.ts:

```
setupDeepLink(){
    this.deeplinks.route({
      '/viewdiary/:id/public': 'viewdiary/:id/public'
    }).subscribe((match)=>{
      console.log('deeplink matched', match);
      const internalPath = `${match.$route}/${match.$args['id']}/${match.$route}`;
      console.log(internalPath);
      this.zone.run(()=>{
        this.general.goToPage(internalPath);
      });
    },
    nomatch=>{
      // nomatch.$link - the full link data
      console.error("Got a deeplink that didn't match", nomatch);
    })
  };
```

My Public diary Page link is `'https://www.example.com/diary/12542/public';`
it looks like a routing issue tried many thing changes names but nothing works.  I am clueless what going wrong.

Comment: Are you running `setupDeepLink ()` inside a `platform.ready` callback ?

Comment: Yes. it is inside `patform.ready` and it is working and checking deeplink. But the issue is it always return match not found.

Comment: I may be dumb but shouldn't the link be `'https://www.example.com/viewdiary/12542/public'`

Comment: @jona303 i have tried it as well. I did change URL and routing names etc etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out how to achieve it with the help of [Another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50854204/5909026) on Stackoverflow

```
import { Platform, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}


this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
    '/viewdiary/:diary/:id/:public': 'viewdiary'
  }).subscribe((match) => {
       console.log('success' + JSON.stringify(match));
  }, (noMatch) => {          
       console.log('error' + JSON.stringify(noMatch));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this approach did not work either. So, in my application I handle deep links as follows:

```js
const {App}: { App: AppPlugin } = Plugins;
...

export class AppComponent {
    private setupDeepLinks(): void {
        App.addListener('appUrlOpen', (data: any) => {
            this.ngZone.run(() => {
                // Example url: https://my-domain.com/tabs/tab2
                // slug = /tabs/tab2
                const slug = data.url.split('my-domain.com').pop();
                if (slug) {
                    this.router.navigateByUrl(slug);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Or you can implement your own more complex logic inside the listener if needed

Comment: i think it is for Capacitor right? i am using cordova! so if you can help me with cordova it will be good.

Comment: It should be pretty similar. Let me check

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib, did you try `routeWithNavController` instead of `route`?

Comment: No. let me try with this.

Comment: still same error with `routeWithNavController` ;

Comment: Did you setup plugin correctly? I means this line `cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks
--variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=example.com
--variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/`

Comment: Also did you add `universal-links` to your `config.xml`?

Comment: Did you check the differences between your project configuration and demo project https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-deeplinks-demo ?

Comment: i checked it before and it is way too old. But i will again check it.