# Communication between app and opened window

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building app in `ionic` and `cordova`. In in I'm opening website in browser using `window.open(url, 'targetWindow')` It works, but after some actions I want to pass some data to app but there is no `window.opener` object in browser. Am I able to communicate from browser to app which opened window?

I want this
`App -> window.open -> browser -> window.opener -> App`

But I've got this :/
`App -> window.open -> browser -> no window.opener so I cannot pass params to app`

Comment: Just a Suggestion: use ionic `DeepLinks` to open app again from your browser( you can also pass data in deeplinks). I've not done it yet but it will give you directions. for `deeplink` implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068298/ionic-4-deeplink-plugin-return-false-route-not-matched

Comment: also take a look at this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-native-inappbrowser-pass-url-parameters-to-app/89872/7

Comment: Thanks I did it with deeplinks :)

Comment: Glad it helped you. do you mind sharing solution as answer so others can get help. also Vote Up :D

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib go ahead. I'll mark it as correct anwser

Comment: Thanks but Answer your question with the solution you used.

Comment: If You post answer point would go to Your account, right? I'll mark Your answer as correct.