# How to implement Ionic Deeplink when link has multiple parameters

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking, ionic-native

I need someone to explain to me how can I use `ionic-deeplinking` in my project.
The scenario is this I have a link `https://dev-testing-app.web.app/auth-handler?mode=action&oobCode=code`, and I want to redirect the user when they clicked the link to a certain page. The problem is I don't know what endpoint should I place in line `23` since the link has multiple query parameter which are `mode` and `code`. Is there a way to implement this?
[image]

Comment: For reference check this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/66068298/5909026

But what exactly you have to do is to change your page routing. for example:
`yourPage/:firstParam/:secondParam/:thirdParam` .

Comment: I'm using firebase `resetPassword`, I can't change the page routing since it is the default url link that is generated by firebase.

Comment: i am talking about your `app.routing.module.ts` file. Change your page routing for resetting your password.