# IONIC DEEPLINKS BUGS : Impossible redirection to deeplinks

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking

I have a problem on Ionic with deeplinks.

When I open my safari browser from my iPhone 11 emulator, I type the following link:
myapp://.
From this moment, a pop up appears and proposes me to open this page from my application. It works well.

But when I want to set my deeplinks to redirect me to another page of my app, it does not work anymore. Each time, it is the home page of my application that opens.

Here you can see my `app.component.ts` file

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.statusBar.show();
        this.splashScreen.hide();
        this.initDeeplinks();
    });
}
initDeeplinks() {
    this.deeplinks.route({
        '/signup': SignupPage,
        '/login': LoginPage
    }).subscribe((match) => {
            alert(match);
            // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
            // match.$args - the args passed in the link
            // match.$link - the full link data
            console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
        },
        (nomatch) => {
            // nomatch.$link - the full link data
            console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
        });
}
```

Comment: what link are you trying to redirect and also add whats inside your `console.log()`

Comment: Hi Najam,
I'm trying to redirect to "myapp://login" that should open my LoginComponent. And there are nothing inside my console.log. I think that the function initDeeplinks() isn't called ... However I call it in the function initializeApp() after the platform is ready.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068298/ionic-4-deeplink-plugin-return-false-route-not-matched