# Ionic Deeplinks doesn't enter either match or nomatch

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, android-deep-link

I've been facing a problem with ionic deeplinks in android. It's doesn't enter either of the callback passed to subscribe.

```
 this.deeplinks.route({}).subscribe(
  (match) => {
    alert("MATCH");
  },
  (nomatch) => {
    alert("NO MATCH");
  }
);
```

So i initialize the app in this way in my app.component.ts:

```
 setupDeeplinks() {
   alert("Start setup of deeplinks");
   this.deeplinks.route({}).subscribe(
   (match) => {
    alert("MATCH");
   },
  (nomatch) => {
    alert("NO MATCH");
  }
);
```

}

but when i ru the app on my android device, when i click the link the smarphone doesn't open my app.

My config.xml are:

```
    <platform name="android">
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
        android:name="eu.apistech.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
      android:name=".activities.DeepLinkActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
      <!-- Accept chrome links -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
          <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="dev.joinbeeyard.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/"/>
      </intent-filter>

      <!-- Accept adb data flag -->
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="dev.joinbeeyard.com"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>




    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
</application>

<!-- Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- Geolocation API -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

i'm facing this problem for a long a time and i need help please.

Thanks,
David Ferreira

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068298/ionic-4-deeplink-plugin-return-false-route-not-matched

Comment: thanks! it help me very much